# Create Select2 from normal select in Wordpress, Woocommerce Add Categories Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

Good Day

I can get a selection to work on with categories dynamically, it works but I cannot get it to work as a select2 for some reason.

I'm using Wordpress 5.7 and Woocommerce 5.1.0

please see code below

```
    <?php
      $args = array( 'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' =>'-1'
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
echo '<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="crosssell" multiple="multiple">';
foreach( $product_categories as $category ){
    echo "<option value = '" . esc_attr( $category->slug ) . "'>" . esc_html( $category->name ) . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><br/>";
      ?>
<script type="text/javascript">   
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});</script>
```

But I get an error in the google console

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
> at edit-tags.php:1178

this is the line that gives the error

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you use jQuery in Wordpress you must use "jQuery", "$" is not recognized.

Try editing in this way:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">   
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
});</script>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it thank you for your help? voted correct question

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped, how can I call the selected back the old one was like this <input name="crosssell" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($crosssell); ?>">